# Button drawing wrongly background after text size changed

Tags: android, android-layout

I am putting a bunch of buttons in `LinearLayout`, with `weight=1` for each. The problem is, that when the `setTextSize` gets called, it sometimes changes the space the background is drawn on (so if the new text size is smaller the one button has perceived height FE 2/3 of all the other buttons). The `onSizeChanged` gets never called even though the size drawn changes. The button does not change it's postion (debug by getLocationInWindow) neither it's size (getWidth, getHeight).

Am I doing something wrong, or is there at least a way to fix it?

MainActivity:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewGroup mainLayout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
        mainLayout.addView(l);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            Button b = new Button(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams p1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200);
            p1.weight = 1;
            b.setLayoutParams(p1);
            b.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            l.addView(b);
        }

        Button b = ((Button)l.getChildAt(7));
        b.setTextSize(50f);
    }
}
```

And for it to be all, XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="dracek.fit.cvut.cz.test.MainActivity">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried all this for the button but no change:

```
requestLayout();
invalidate();
ViewParent vp = getParent();
if (vp != null)
    vp.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Please post an [mcve].  All code should  compile without errors  other than what you are asking about.  In particular,  none of your code is in a class.

Comment: post your linearlayout xml too

Comment: Call `requestLayout()` after `setTextSize()`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Done, sorry for the first post.

Comment: @yanivtwin it is created dynamically, without any parameters

Comment: @azizbekian you can look to the bottom of my post, I already tried that, nothing changed

Comment: After some debuging, the real size of the button does not change (still 200), but the background gets drawn only for a part of the button, still I have no idea how to change that

Comment: Is the code you posted here minimal? Is every line necessary to understand your question and reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice ok, sorry, you were right, I made it much more minimal, though I don't think I can make it any shorter now.

Answer (score 0):

So I will answer myself if noone else does so.

In the end I found out, that the LinearLayout is for whatever reason trying to have all the text baselines in the same height, thus moving the buttons. Adding one line solves the problem:

```
p1.gravity =Gravity.FILL;
```